# Use LocalStorage variables in php

Tags: javascript, php

I have some value inside localtorage.
For example, a code like this has set the localStorage :

```
<script>
    localStorage.setItem('jeton', 'toto');
    localStorage.setItem('cle', 'l1s7T4O7p79XDS9UwfG4YTBhkjoybjHBydC74VxgmXk=')
</script>
```

Then the file control.php want to  access to  the local storage :

```
<?php
    $token2  = JWT::decode(
         $jeton, 
        $cle , // The signing key
        array('HS512') 
    );
```

The problem is that $jeton et $cle has no value

How to put the localStorage.getItem('jeton') inside $jeton ?

Best regards.

Comment: You need to use some Ajax and https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-differences-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is, it not possible to access `localStorage` at PHP, as `localStorage` is kept on the client-side only, and there is no data transmitted to the server-side.

Also, you can only get the data with JavaScript and you can send it to the server-side with Ajax only.

The alternative would be to use `cookies`, if its a simple string, as cookies are sent to the server in the request headers, and accessible at PHP

Answer (score 0):

`Javascript` runs in client-side and `PHP` runs in server-side. There is no way that they can have access in different environments.

The only way is by using requests. You should send the value from `javascript` to `php` using `ajax` from `jQuery`

Example using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/file.php",
        type: "post",
        data: { name: localStorage.getItem('jeton') }
});
```

Then in `file.php` you would get that value like this:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

You can read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/whatis/whatis_ajax.asp) about ajax.

Answer (score 0):

So inside control.php :

```
<script>
//var jeton = localStorage.getItem('jeton');
//var cle = localStorage.getItem('cle');
$.ajax({
    url: "/control.php",
    type: "post",
    data: { jeton: localStorage.getItem('jeton') }
});
</script>
```

And then inside php:

```
$jeton = $_POST['jeton'];
```

But when i execute this I have the error :
Undefined index: jeton in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\menergie-client\control.php on line 42.

as if $_POST['jeton'] was not set.

Is it possible to put the javascript and the php in the same file ???